# select() does not give timeout inside a Bash script

Tags: c++

I have a problem that the select() does not give timeout when I run the program inside a Bash script file. This is my implementation:

```
#include <sys/select.h>

bool checkKeyPressed()
{
  struct timeval tv;

  tv.tv_sec = 1;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  fd_set descriptor;
  const int input = 0;

  FD_ZERO(&descriptor);
  FD_SET(input, &descriptor);

  return select(1, &descriptor, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0;
}
```

// strace result after running the program directly (correct that there is a timeout)

```
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {1, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
```

// strace result to run the application inside a bash script file (no timeout)

```
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {1, 0})      = 1 (in [0], left {0, 999996})
read(0, "", 1)                          = 0
```

How can I change the function to get it working with also running under the Bash script?

Comment: FWIW your program works fine on my machine (MacOS/X), even when I run it from within a simple Bash script.  Perhaps it is something particular to your bash script that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at the `read` call in the trace, you will notice it returns zero meaning end-of-file.

When a file descriptor is at EOF (or remote socket closed, etc), the descriptor is readable with `read` returning zero.

If you would have pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in the interactive shell, you would have gotten the same result.

Comment: Yes, that is clear. My question here is how can I change the code to get select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {1, 0})      = 0 (Timeout) when I wrap the program inside the bashscript. thanks

Comment: @olidev It seems you can't. You have to work around this problem some other way.

Comment: any alternative for select()? Thanks

Comment: @olidev Never mind the solution you have, what is the actual problem you try to solve?

Comment: select() does not get timeout if I wrap the program inside a bashscript file. So I mean I run the program under the bashscript file

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a 1-second timeout don't pass any file descriptors to `select()`. In this case `select()` works as a portable `sleep()` function.

Comment: Do you mean: select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv) then I dont get whether there is a key pressed?

Comment: I meant `select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv)`.

Comment: The question doesn't describe it as such, but from the code provided it looks like the program is intended to return after 1 second, *or* after some input was received on `stdin`, whichever comes first.